Android WebViewでのスワイプによる挙動
AndroidでWebViewを使用したアプリ開発をしています。
Swipeをするとページが戻る・進むことができますが
HTML上にslickなどのスライダーが配置いてある場合、そのスライダー上でスワイプをすると
スライダーの切替ではなくページの戻る・進むが動いてしまいます。
欲を言えばスライダー上でスワイプするとページそのままでスライダー切り替え。
スライダー以外でスワイプするとページを戻る・進む　という動作を希望しているのですが、、、
なにかいい方法をご存じの方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。
